# Flutter authentication error although I am passing the required arguments to the endpoint

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to sign up a user by posting to the endpoint with the required data, it works perfectly but the API returns an error message of `fullName` is required. As you can see clearly, I am passing the name to the `fullName` in the call.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> signup({
    required String name,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.post(Api.SIGN_UP, data: {
        'fullName': name,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
      });

      final responseData = response.data;
      print(responseData.toString());
      return responseData;
    } on DioError catch (err) {
      print(err.error);
      throw CustomException(err.message);
    } catch (error) {
      throw CustomException('An error occured. Please try again later');
    }
  }
```

Below is the endpoint I want to make the call to:

```
class Api {
  // DIO OPTIONS
  static var options = BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/',
    connectTimeout: 5000,
    receiveTimeout: 3000,
  );
  static const SIGN_UP = 'onboarding/signup';
}
```

I tried in using postman to do it and it works correctly and signs up the user. I don't know where the error is coming from, whether the Dio or the backend.

Comment: can send the error message here?

Comment: { success: false, message: full name is required }. It has a status code of 200

Comment: this may be the end point don't search for the username , email and password in the data section , try to set them in the param attribute in the post method.

Comment: it returns to you that her couldn't find the full name because its the first key that the end point search for

Comment: It receives query params..and I have used that too but still not working

Comment: Can you send them to query param not data and send the error message or image of the error

Answer (score 0):

Add response type, and content type to your deo option

```
static var options = BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/api/',
    connectTimeout: 5000,
    receiveTimeout: 3000,
    responseType: ResponseType.plain,
    contentType: Headers.jsonContentType,
  );
```

Comment: It is still not working..any help?

Comment: the problem is from your server side, what kind of data you are returning from the server side you should set your response type to json

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the backend was accepting only data of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
So I had to pass `options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType)` as options in the post method